# How to trigger an aerender command from a web page

Tags: after-effects, aerender

What's the easiest way to trigger an aerender command from a web page?

Using [Templater](http://aescripts.com/templater/), I can create renders based on google spreadsheets, but I can't find a good description of how to trigger a render remotely.  Is there a good howto guide somewhere?  Maybe using PHP or something (not an expert on this)... PS: I'm using a Mac

Comment: In general php is not made for this purpose, I would you advise against it. Usually then it only remains ruby and python on a web server. I would recommend python, since it's often used and there are many film-related libraries. Also, there is a build-in csv module to parse a spreadsheet. I thought it's a good idea to include site relevant code (how to trigger aerender), because all the other topics seems more fitting for stackoverflow (imo). It's a really interessting question, but it's also quite complex, thus my answer is a rough overview only, so let me know what else you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on which scripting languages your web server supports.

#### Main requirements

1. The language should be able to **execute the application**
2. The language should **provide secure access** the files on the server or a network
3. The language should provide methods to **assembly file paths** (e.g. relative to absolute paths)
4. The language should provide **interaction methods** for connecting the webpage (user input) and *your application*, also see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_application_framework

---

#### Execute aerender via python

Assuming your webserver supports [python](https://www.python.org/), execute the app via [python's subprocess module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html). *You only have to make sure that you can call* `aerender` *from your command line properly.*

```py
# import subprocess module to call aerender
import subprocess 

# create a aerender argument list
args = ['aerender', '-project', 'path_to_file']
process = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
```

In order to **batch process** a folder of `.aep` files you'll need to iterate through the files:

```py
#import os module
import os 

# set the path to your aep folder
path = '/home/user/Desktop/aep-files'    # linux or osx
# path = r'c:\some\directory\aep-files'  # windows, the r is important
# path = 'c:/some/directory\aep-files'   # windows (alternative)

# make sure the files are .aep files
aep_file_folder = [f for f in os.listdir(path) if f.endswith('.aep')] 

# iterate through the list
for i in aep_file_folder:
    # setup correct filepath for aeps
    file_path = os.path.join(path,i)

    # call aerender with the correct arguments
    subprocess.call(['aerender', '-project', file_path])
```

**Note:** If there is no need to communicate (e.g. getting the output of aerender) you can simply use `subprocess.call` instead.